# Ag-param() called before ag-register-params

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, scss-mixins

I try to generate a custom theme for Ag-Grid with the new theme mixin. But I always get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/app/style.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
              ^
      Ag-param() called before ag-register-params
      in C:\Development\WebApp\node_modules\@ag-grid-enterprise\all-modules\dist\styles\mixins\_ag-theme-params.scss (line 191, column 16)
```

Styles:

```
@import "../../../../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.scss";
@import "../../../../node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-material/sass/ag-theme-material-mixin";

.ag-theme-custom-test {
  @include ag-theme-material();
}
```

Comment: Have you found solution? I have similar issue

Comment: No, I have implemented different themes with different classes and did some overridings there.

Comment: @MinsikPark did you find anything on this? I just received the same issue.

Comment: @chris-eikrem look at my answer. I have found a solution for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problem. The generation of the theme must be done on load of the app. I had outsourced my Ag-Grid theming into another file which will be imported.

---

Old outsourced theming file:

```
@import '~@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.scss';
@import '~@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-material/sass/_ag-theme-material-mixin.scss';

.ag-theme-material{
    @include ag-theme-material(
        (
            background-color: green
        )
    );
}
```

Old styles.scss(which is initially loaded -> see angular.json config)

```
.dark-theme {
  @import './outsourced-ag-grid-theme.scss'  // not working

  REST OF THE OTHER THEMING STUFF....
}
```

---

New outsourced theming file:

```
@import '~@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.scss';
@import '~@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-material/sass/_ag-theme-material-mixin.scss';

.dark-theme .ag-theme-material{
    @include ag-theme-material(
        (
            background-color: green
        )
    );
}
```

New styles.scss(which is initially loaded -> see angular.json config)

```
.dark-theme {
  REST OF THE OTHER THEMING STUFF....
}

@import './outsourced-ag-grid-theme.scss'  // place it outside and it will be initially load
```

---

I hope I could help other devs out there. If you have questions, just let me know.

Comment: I upvoted your question because I'm having this problem today. I want to be able to call something like `line-height: ag-param(grid-size) * 5;` but get this error: `SassError: "ag-param() called before ag-register-params"
   ╷
66 │     $resolved: -ag-param-unchecked($name);` And this is even with `@import "~@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/mixins/_ag-theme-params.scss";` at the top, as https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-grid/themes-customising/#function-ag-param says. I don't understand your answer here. If you could elaborate, I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: My problem was that my Ag-Grid theming file wasn't processed initially. As far as I understood the theming file must be declared in the angular.json file or imported into a file  wich is declared there (in my case it was styles.scss). But keep in mind it must be imported at the top of the file and NOT in a nested class there! If you prepare an example, I will have a look at it.